# This SDK method is not supported on this Messenger client. Please upgrade

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

Using the Facebook MessengerExtensions library to get the Page Scoped UserID from a desktop web browser messenger webview returns the error message "This SDK method is not supported on this Messenger client. Please upgrade" (desktop, Chrome 60). It works fine when the webview is opened from the Messenger app on Android.

Another SO topic suggested using `MessengerExtensions.getContext()`, but this didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of getContext was wrong:

See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/context

```
MessengerExtensions.getContext(<?php echo FACEBOOK_APP_ID;?>,
  function success(result){
    alert(result.psid);
    console.log("success", result);
  },
  function error(result){
    console.log("error", result);
  }
);
```